# Are this set and this sigma algebra independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space, $\{\mathcal{A}_i\}_i$ a family of sets and $\mathcal{B}$ another set.
Suppose $\forall i$ $\mathcal{A}_i $ and $\mathcal{B}$ are independent.

Set $\sigma(\{\mathcal{A}_i \})$ the sigma algebra generated by $\{\mathcal{A}_i\}_i$.
Are $\mathcal{B}$ and any set from $\sigma(\{\mathcal{A}_i \})$ independent?

Comment: What do you mean by " independent"?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are independent if $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true if $(A_i)_i$ is closed under intersection, that is if for all $i,j$, there exists $k$ such that $A_i\cap A_j=A_k$. Otherwise not necessarily.

For example, $\Omega=\{0,1,2,3\}$, $\mathcal F=\mathcal P(\Omega)$,
$$
\mathbb P(\{0\})=\mathbb P(\{1\})=\mathbb P(\{2\})=\mathbb P(\{3\})=\frac14,
$$
$\mathcal A_1=\{0,1\}$, $\mathcal A_2=\{1,3\}$ and $\mathcal B=\{1,2\}$.

Then
$$
\mathbb P(\mathcal A_1\cap\mathcal B)=\mathbb P(\{1\})=\frac14=\frac12\times\frac12=\mathbb P(\{0,1\})\mathbb P(\{1,2\})=\mathbb P(\mathcal A_1)\mathbb P(\mathcal B).
$$

Similarly, $\mathbb P(\mathcal A_2\cap\mathcal B)=\mathbb P(\mathcal A_2)\mathbb P(\mathcal B)$. We have $\{1\}\in\sigma(\mathcal A_1,\mathcal A_2)$, yet
$$
\mathbb P(\{1\}\cap\mathcal B)=\mathbb P(\{1\})=\frac14\neq\frac14\times\frac12=\mathbb P(\{1\})\mathbb P(\mathcal B).
$$

Comment: Thanks, it was just what I was looking for. With your hint now I can prove if $(B_t)$ is Brownian Motion and s > t, $B_s-B_t$ and $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(\{B_x: x \leq t \})$ are independent.